# Utilities for various builtins #1

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, ecmascript-6, extension-methods, helper

This is an iterative review. The next iteration is located here: [Utilities for Various Builtins #2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/194763/utilities-for-various-builtins-2)
This code puts several builtins (And a few non-builtins) into the base classes.

```
  const XtraUtils = {};
  class Utility {
    constructor(ofWhat){
      this.utils = {};
      this.aidsIn = ofWhat;
    }
    activate() {
      for (var x in this.utils) {
        window[this.aidsIn].prototype[x] = this.utils[x];
      }
    }
    addUtil(util, name) {
      this.utils[name] = util;
    }
  };
  XtraUtils.Number = new Utility("Number");
  XtraUtils.String = new Utility("String");
  XtraUtils.Array = new Utility("Array");
  XtraUtils.Number.addUtil(function(in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max) {
    return (this - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
  }, "map");
  XtraUtils.Number.addUtil(function(inputBase = 10, outputBase = 10){parseInt(this, inputBase).toString(outputBase)}, "toBaseN");
  XtraUtils.Number.addUtil(function(n){
    return Math.pow(this, n);
  }, "toTheNthPower");
  XtraUtils.Number.addUtil(function(){
    return Math.ceil(this);
  }, "ceil");
  XtraUtils.Number.addUtil(function(){
    return Math.floor(this);
  }, "floor");
  XtraUtils.Number.addUtil(function() {
    return Math.sqrt(this);
  }, "sqrt");
  XtraUtils.Array.addUtil(function() {
    const i = this.map(function(item) {
      return typeof item == "number";
    });
    const isAllNums = i.indexOf(false) == -1;
    if (!isAllNums) {
      throw "The array must be all numbers.";
      return;
    };
    let max = 0;
    let isFirst = true;
    this.forEach(function(item) {
      if (isFirst || item > max) {
        max = item;
        isFirst = false;
      };
    });
    return max;
  }, "max");
  XtraUtils.Array.addUtil(function() {
    const i = this.map(function(item) {
      return typeof item == "number";
    });
    const isAllNums = i.indexOf(false) == -1;
    if (!isAllNums) {
      throw "The array must be all numbers.";
      return;
    };
    let min = 0;
    let isFirst = true;
    this.forEach(function(item) {
      if (isFirst || item < min) {
        min = item;
        isFirst = false;
      };
    });
    return min;
  }, "min");
  XtraUtils.Array.addUtil(function() {
    let i = this.map(function(item) {
      return typeof item == "number";
    });
    const isAllNums = i.indexOf(false) == -1;
    if (!isAllNums) {
      throw "The array must be all numbers.";
      return;
    };
    let total = 0;
    var isFirst = true;
    this.forEach(function(item) {
      total += item;
    });
    const mean = total / this.length;
    return mean;
  }, "mean");
```

Feel free to use the utils if you like.

Comment: When adding additional information you should [edit] your question instead of adding a comment. Learn more about comments including when to comment and when not to in [the Help Center page about Comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most part, this looks good to me. Your api is clear and I really like that you have to activate the utility before the prototype is modified. However, there's always room for improvement :)

1. You provide the `Utility.activate` function, it would be useful to also have a `Utility.deactivate` function.
2. `addUtil` taking `name` as the second parameter seems odd to me. On a longer utility method like `min`, `max` or `mean` it was not immediately obvious to me what the function did - I had to skip to the end or figure it out from the code.
3. Be consistent with your naming scheme. In most of the code you use `camelCase`, but in the parameters for `Number.map` you use `snake_case`.
4. Why is the `inputBase` the first parameter in `toBaseN`? Presumably, if I have a number it is already in base 10. This function will also have issues if you use `0.0000001`, plug `0.0000001.toString()` into your console and you will get `1e-7` instead of what you expected.
5. `toTheNthPower` is just `pow` on the `Math` object. I would use the same convention here.
6. Don't throw strings. Throw a `new Error(str)` or just `Error(str)`. This makes it much easier for error tracking systems to give you helpful stack traces.
7. Returning `0` as a signal number if the array is empty is not a good idea. `0` could exist in an array. I'd recommend using the convention of `Math.max` and `Math.min` and returning `-Infinity` and `Infinity` respectively.
8. Mapping over the array to create an array of booleans is very inefficient. If I create an array with `['hi'].concat([1].repeat(1e9))` you still go through every single item in the array. Instead of doing this, bail out as soon as you hit a failing condition. `[].every` and `[].some` can be of help here. `const isAllNums = this.every(item => typeof item == 'number')`
9. Speaking of `Math.max` and `Math.min`, you should use them! You can use `Math.max.apply(Math, this)` or if your environment supports the spread operator, you can just use `Math.max(...this)`. If desired, you can check if this returns `NaN` and throw an error to maintain the current API instead of returning `NaN` for arrays with non-numbers.
10. Don't use `for..in` loops to loop over keys of objects. Either use `for (const key of Object.keys(this.utils))` or `Object.keys(this.utils).forEach(`. This will help you avoid problems with built in values like `toString`.
11. In this case, it is probably a better fit to use a `Map` instead of a plain object to hold the utils.
12. What happens if you want to use these utils in Node? They break - `window` is not defined. This might not be a consideration, but quite a lot of code runs on Node now.
13. What happens if you want to define utilities for an object which is not exposed on the global? Instead of passing a string into the constructor of `Utility`, I'd recommend passing in an object instead. `new Utility(Array)`
14. Instead of looping through the array multiple times for `mean`, I'd recommend checking each element of the array as you add it to the sum. Maintaining your current API, here's how I'd implement that function.

    ```js
    function mean(arr) {
      return arr.reduce((total, item) => {
        if (typeof item !== 'number') {
          throw new Error("The array must be all numbers.")
        }
        return total + item
      }, 0) / arr.length
    }
    ```