# Utilities for Various Builtins #2

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, ecmascript-6, extension-methods, helper

This is the final iteration of an iterative review. The previous iteration can be found here: [Utilities for various builtins #1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/194469/utilities-for-various-builtins)

This code solves the following issue:

```
var i = 9
i.sqrt();     // 3
Math.sqrt(i); // 3
```

And other similar dilemmas. It also saves you from having to write your own mean and max function. I've also been told this is known as "syntatic sugar".

*It's also worth it's weight in keypresses.*

```
/**
 * Adds some utilities to the base classes.
 * Note that this is modular and is able to modify any class it is given.
 * @author FreezePhoenix
 * @version 1.1.0
 */

/**
 * @type {Object}
 * @constant
 */
const XtraUtils = {};
/**
 * @class
 * @classdesc Enables utilities to be added to classes.
 */
class Utility {
   /**
    * Create a new utility
    * @param {Object} ofWhat               - First part of the filter to test if it is a constructor.
    * @param {Function} ofWhat.constructor - Second part of the filter.
    * @return {Boolean}                    - false means something went wrong, true means it succeded.
    * @this Utility
    * @throws {TypeError} The first argument of Utility must be a class.
    */
    constructor(ofWhat) {
        if (typeof ofWhat == 'function' && typeof new ofWhat() === 'object') {
            this.utils = {};
            Object.defineProperty(this, 'aidsIn', {
                value: ofWhat,
                writable: false
            });
            this.Activated = [];
            this.OverWritten = {};
            return true;
        } else {
            console.error(
                'new Utility expects an object template to be passed as the first argument.'
            );
            return false;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Activates the utilities in this Utility instance.
     * @this Utility
     */
    activate() {
        for (const x in this.utils) {
            if (this.aidsIn.prototype[x]) {
                this.OverWritten[x] = this.aidsIn.prototype[x].valueOf();
            }
            this.aidsIn.prototype[x] = this.utils[x];
            this.Activated.push(x);
        }
    }
   /**
    * @this Utility
    */
    deactivate() {
        this.Activated.forEach((item, index) => {
            if (this.OverWritten[item]) {
                this.aidsIn.prototype[item] = this.OverWritten[item];
            } else {
                delete this.aidsIn.prototype[item];
            };
        });
        this.Activated = [];
    }
    /**
     * @this Utility
     */
    addUtil(name, util) {
        this.utils[name] = util;
    }
}
XtraUtils.Number = new Utility(Number);
XtraUtils.String = new Utility(String);
XtraUtils.Array = new Utility(Array);
XtraUtils.Number.addUtil('map', function(in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max) {
    return (this - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
});
XtraUtils.Number.addUtil(function(inputBase = 10, outputBase = 10) {
    parseInt(this, inputBase).toString(outputBase);
}, 'toBaseN');
XtraUtils.Number.addUtil('pow', function(n) {
    return Math.pow.apply(Math, this, n);
});
XtraUtils.Number.addUtil('ceil', function() {
    return Math.ceil.apply(Math,this);
});
XtraUtils.Number.addUtil('floor', function() {
    return Math.floor.apply(Math,this);
});
XtraUtils.Number.addUtil('sqrt', function() {
    return Math.sqrt.apply(Math,this);
});
XtraUtils.Array.addUtil('max', function() {
    return Math.max.apply(Math, this);
});
XtraUtils.Array.addUtil('min', function() {
    return Math.min.apply(Math, this);
});
XtraUtils.Array.addUtil('mean', function() {
    let total = 0;
    var isFirst = true;
    this.forEach(function(item) {
        if (typeof item === 'string') {
            throw Error('Item must be all numbers');
        }
        total += item;
    });
    const mean = total / this.length;
    return mean;
});
```

Comment: Could you describe the intent of extending and problem being solved? I did check the previous version of the question; it misses a specific description too.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko Will do.

Comment: Yes, a bit. It's still not stated directly. Do I understand correctly, that this code attempts to provide the extension methods _in abstract_ context; as in "syntax sugar"?

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Utility` class should keep track of its own activation state, otherwise calling `.activate()` multiple times on the same instance (without calling `.deactivate()` in between) might cause some problems; also, in the current code, calling `.addUtil()` after `.activate()` leaves the instance in a limbo state, where the method name is added to `this.utils` but isn't actually available on the aided class's prototype, even though the instance is activated. I can imagine this leading to some frustrating debugging on a more complex project. I'd suggest that calling `.addUtil()` on an activated `Utility` instance should either immediately activate the added function, or throw an `Error` (this sounds more consistent with your approach).

*(also, as a side note, I wouldn't call this syntactic sugar. Sugar is just simpler way of writing something. e.g. `{ ...obj }` is sugar for `Object.assign({}, obj)`; it doesn't actually add new functionality, which your code certainly does)*

Comment: I've decided to do a mix of both. If override is present, then do it no matter what and instantly activate it. But otherwise, throw an error.